# Finding $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \int_x^{x+x^a}\frac{dt}{\sqrt t \log t} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, improper-integrals

Let $f$ be the integrand and $g$ the integral. It is continuous on $(0,+\infty)$ so it is on $[x,x+x^a]$ for all $x>0$.

The solution states

> $f$ is decreasing on $(0,+\infty)$, therefore by the monotonicity of the integral with respect to the integrand, we have $$f(x+x^a)\cdot x^a\le g(x)\le f(x)\cdot x^a.$$

From this, it's easy to conclude, but I don't get how the inequality was derived.

---

Also, is it true that for $a\le0$, as $x\to+\infty$, we have $$g(x)=\int_0^{x^a}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t+x}\log(t+x)}\le \int_0^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t+x}\log(t+x)}\to0$$? I know this agrees with the correct result that $g(x)\to0$ if $a\le1/2$ and $g(x)\to+\infty$ if $a>1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality you're asking about is derived from comparing the region of integration to two different rectangles. The expression on the left, $f(x+x^a)\cdot x^a$ is the area of a rectangle whose base is the domain of integration, and whose height is the value of $f$ at the right end. Since $f$ is decreasing, this rectangle is contained in the region of integration, so it's area is less than the integral.

Similarly, the expression $f(x)\cdot x^a$ is the area of a rectangle whose base is the domain of integration, and whose height is given by the value of $f$ at the *left* end of the domain. This rectangle contains the region of integration, so its area is greater.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one more thing, does the last paragraph in my question make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure. Did you mean to put exactly the same integral on either side of that $\le$ sign?

Comment: Oops, no, I've corrected the typo

Comment: I see. That makes sense now. For a second, I thought $g$ was the same function as in the first part of the question, but now I see you're defining a new $g(x)$, and what you wrote is certainly true. The inequality holds because $x^a\le 1$, and the second integral goes to $0$ because it's bounded from above by $1/(\sqrt{x}\log x)$.